# How to delete query with a checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I'm struggling with writing a code that will delete a query if I select a checkbox and press delete.

UPDATE: code updated as you guys proposed, only thing that doesn't work now
is when checkbox checked and submitted it won't delete the query

This is my while:

```
$query="SELECT id,datum,titel,artikel FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo ("<div id=\"artikeltitel\" align=\"center\">
    <div id=\"containerdatum\">".$row['datum']."</div>
    <div id=\"containertitel\">".$row['titel']."</div>
    <div id=\"container3\" style=\"font-size:12px;\">".$row['id']."
    <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" id=\"checkbox\"  value=\"".$row['id']."\"       />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class=\"container\" align=\"center\">
    <h2 class=\"acc_trigger\"><a href=\"#\"> &#187; </a></h2>
    <div class=\"acc_container\">
    <div class=\"block\">".$row['artikel']."</div>
    <div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"http://www.zpb-polonez.be/user.php\" data-num-    posts=\"10\" data-width=\"678\" style=\"margin-top:2px;\"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    ");
```

}
this is the part where i read my sql, don't know if its all ok, most of the code
i copied from my other work that i learned at school

```
require_once("inc/connection.php");
mysql_select_db("nieuws");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
$id = $_POST['id'];
$datum = $_POST["datum"];
$titel = $_POST["titel"];
$artikel = $_POST["artikel"];
$checkbox = $_POST["checkbox"];
$titel = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br(htmlentities($_POST["titel"])));
$artikel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["artikel"]);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$datum = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $datum)));
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['titel']) && !empty($_POST['artikel']) && !empty($_POST['datum'])){
        $query="INSERT INTO nieuws (id,datum,titel,artikel) VALUES ('$id','$datum','$titel','$artikel')";
        $datum = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $datum)));
        str_replace('<br />', "\n", $textarea);
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        header("location: user.php");
        $juist1 = true;
        }else{
        $fout1 = true;
        }
    }if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id){
        $del_id=$checkbox; 
        $sql="DELETE FROM nieuws WHERE id='$del_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        header("location: user.php");
        }
    }
```

}

Already have a submit

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="verwijderen" />
</form>
```

Comment: hmm.. are you combinating the while and elseif? elseif can be used after a if.. not after a while. is the while loop placed in a if statment?

Comment: no the there is a if before the elsif but i only copied this part, no the while loop is not in a if statment, like i told php is not my specialty :-)

Comment: header("location: user.php"); should be after forloop

Comment: Taking a quick look, I noticed id=\"checkbox\" is used several times (when there are more then one checkboxes). Id's must be unique (that would not solve the problem though, but you have answers down below that would)

Comment: Are you obliged to 'delete'. Could you issue an UPDATE instead which set a flag to 'hidden'?

Comment: what do you mean strawberry?

Comment: I don't like granting the DELETE privilege to users. Also, if a user DELETEs then they cannot easily 'undo'. If instead they issue an UPDATE (e.g. UPDATE my_table SET hidden = 1 WHERE id = x), then from the user's POV, the record is deleted, but referential integrity is maintained and the record can easily be 'undeleted/"unhidden"' if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

**Delete Script:**

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
 foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id){
    $sql="DELETE FROM nieuws WHERE id='$del_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
 }
 header("location: user.php");
}
```

While script:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<?php
$query="SELECT id,datum,titel,artikel FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    echo ("<div id=\"artikeltitel\" align=\"center\">
        <div id=\"containerdatum\">".$row['datum']."</div>
        <div id=\"containertitel\">".$row['titel']."</div>
        <div id=\"container3\" style=\"font-size:12px;\">".$row['id']."
        <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" id=\"checkbox\"  value=\"".$row['id']."\"       />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"container\" align=\"center\">
        <h2 class=\"acc_trigger\"><a href=\"#\"> &#187; </a></h2>
        <div class=\"acc_container\">
        <div class=\"block\">".$row['artikel']."</div>
        <div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\"http://www.zpb-polonez.be/user.php\" data-num-    posts=\"10\" data-width=\"678\" style=\"margin-top:2px;\"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        ");
 }?>
 <input type="submit" name="delete" value="verwijderen" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Hi Krish, no it doesn't display my values from the database.. ?

Comment: Show me your sql query, it helps more to debug !

Comment: Krish i can't answer my own question now

Comment: @molovhic, Add your sql query in your question section!

Comment: hmm still not retreiving data from database, think it goes wrong that i changed the while list into the row.. ?

Comment: You can use my code!. it will work, copy the select query and check database has values. what errors you have?

Comment: Krish, i copied your code! but when i open page there is no data in the divs were it should be (datum, titel etc..) also the foreach is giving me this error with your script Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in: i'm looking for 2 weeks now how to resolve this problem and nothing seems to work

Comment: ok i got results by changing the while loop in while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ array instead of row but the deleting part won't work

Comment: You need to add `<form>` tag and submit button,

Comment: Check updated while code, you need to add formtag above while. Check my answer!

Comment: done Krish, but still won't delete it out of database :(

Comment: Use my delete script instead of yours!

Comment: It is your script that i'm using

Comment: in your question, i have seen other delete script!

Answer (score 0):

Just having a look at what you have provided, I can't see where you are defining $row in order to populate the checkbox with $row['id']. What if you try simply $id instead of $row['id']?

```
<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" id=\"checkbox\"  value=\"$id\" />
```

If you inspect the HTML, is the value of the checkbox being populated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id){
        $sql="DELETE FROM nieuws WHERE id='$del_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
     }
    header("location: user.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form > //open form
<?php
while loop(conditon)
{?>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val[]" id="checkbox"  value="<?php echo 
$row['id'];?>"/>
<?php
} ?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btn_post">
</form >//closing
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn_post']){
$check_val= $_POST['checkbox_val'];
foreach($check_val as $chval)
{
   $sql="DELETE FROM nieuws WHERE id='$chval[0]'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
}
?>
```